# How would you store a pyramidal image representation in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Suppose I have N images which are a multiresolution representation of a single image (the Nth image being the coarsest one). If my finest scale is a  16x16 image, the next scale is a 8x8 image and so on.
How should I store such data to fastly be able to access, at a given scale and for a given pixel, its unique parent in the next coarser scale and its children at each finest scale?

Comment: I guess it would depend to at least some extent the kind of operations you might want to use on that data. Any insights on it?

Comment: a quadtree would do the trick.

Comment: I will use it in a markov random field framework. For a pixel at a given, I need its parent  and its children at the finest scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a list of numpy arrays. Assuming a scale factor of two, for the *i,j*<sup>th</sup> pixel at scale *n*:

- The indices of its "parent" pixel at scale *n-1* will be `(i//2, j//2)`
- Its "child" pixels at scale *n+1* can be indexed by `(slice(2*i, 2*(i+1)), slice(2*j, 2*(j+1)))`